# Make the first vertical 5 pixels of a background color different to the rest

Tags: css

How would I make the first *vertical* 5 pixels of a background colour blue in a div? So, in other words in the following example there would be a blue bar running across the top for 500 pixels that is 5 pixels high.

To be clear I have a special reason I can not use a border, etc (I wish it was that easy!)

This is what I have so far ([link to fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfJcU/)):

**CSS:**

```
.box {
height: 200px;
width: 500px;
background-color: red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realised I wasn't as clear as I should be on this, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CSS gradient.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jfJcU/2/)**

```
.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 5px, #ff0000 2%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5px,#1e5799), color-stop(2%,#ff0000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 5px,#ff0000 2%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 5px,#ff0000 2%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 5px,#ff0000 2%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 5px,#ff0000 2%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#ff0000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Box-shadow has slightly better browser support than gradients. So that's my method. Frankly, box-shadows are pretty awesome. You can do so many things with them to keep your markup clean.

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 0 0 blue
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 0 0 blue
```

Comment: This works better than the pseudo-element because it is still just a background color. Nice clean solution. http://jsfiddle.net/jfJcU/4/

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd probably opt for a `:before` pseudo-element.

```
.box:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background: blue;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jfJcU/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a 5 pixel left-side border:

```
border-left: 5px solid blue;
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realised I wasn't as clear as I should be on this, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this without a border would probably be adding another div element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box" id="other_box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}
#other_box {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And if you truly wanted it to be the first 5px of 200px main div, you can just change the height of the main div to 195px.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jfJcU/3/

Or, you could wrap the new div within the main div:
http://jsfiddle.net/jfJcU/5/